# Does developer edition salesforce org's run in production environments?

Tags: sandbox, developer-edition

I'm studying for a certification, this doubt came t me, and I couldn't find any documentation regarding this, I was trying to find differences between dev-sandbox and production, besides the size, governance limits and url login, is any other difference?
does developer edition salesforce org's run in production environments? any link will be welcomed. Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*Developer Edition* orgs (*not* developer or developer pro sandboxes) run on production instances. There are various differences between the Developer Edition org and production, primarily around governor limits but potentially also including the slate of enabled features and licenses. A Developer Edition org has no relationship with a production org and should not be expected to match a production org's shape.

*Developer sandboxes* run on sandbox instances. As you're aware, they do come with differences from production, such as data and file storage space, but in other respects such as features and licenses are designed to match production as a Developer Edition org will not.